# Shared printer asking for password

Tags: networking, windows-8, printing, home-networking, network-printer

I have set up printer sharing on a Windows 8 machine. The printer is working from Windows 8 as a local printer. However, other clients (running Windows 7) on the network cannot see it.

I have tried to add a network printer through the Control Panel but it doesn't show up in the list of automatically found printers. So I tried to add it manually, but when I click on the Windows 8 machine icon to look for it, I see that the clients are asked for a username and password, even if I have specifically asked Windows to let clients connect automatically.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe right, I forgot to do that! You should consider turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it ;) – user1301428 28 mins ago

Comment: I did that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off "Password Protected Sharing". That is what did the trick for me.